# Spacebar not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I was on Ubuntu Bionic before and since the spacebar was not working this morning I thought why not update to the new 20.04 as a quick fix solution.

The spacebar works on the new Ubuntu search menu, and even on the login screen, however any kind of application including terminal does not allow me to use it (which was the same with bionic).

What have I done to try to solve this:

```
sudo apt-get reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

I rebooted system, nothing. I tried to reinstall Firefox, still nothing.

What can I do? It’s the only key that isn’t working, and it works on Windows perfectly.

Comment: Possible bad keyboard selection? Internet search for "Ubuntu keyboard selection" shows many results, including  `https://vitux.com/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu/`.